Error creating migration in Entity Framework when a table has 2 foreign keys into another table
I'm trying to create a new table that has 2 foreign keys into another table. I've done this before and didn't have any trouble, but now when I try to create the migration, I'm getting the following error:
$ dotnet ef migrations add RequestLedger
Build started...
Build succeeded.


Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'RequestLedger.NewStatus' of type 'RequestStatusType'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

The relevant parts of my cs files are: RequestLedger.cs:
public long OldStatusId { get; set; }
public long NewStatusId { get; set; }

public virtual RequestStatusType OldStatus { get; set; } = null!;
public virtual RequestStatusType NewStatus { get; set; } = null!;

RequestLedgerEntityTypeConfiguration.cs:
   builder.HasOne(d => d.OldStatus)
        .WithMany(p => p.OldRequestLedgers)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.OldStatusId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    builder.HasOne(d => d.NewStatus)
        .WithMany(p => p.NewRequestLedgers)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.NewStatusId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

RequestStatusType.cs:
    OldRequestLedgers = new HashSet<RequestLedger>();
    NewRequestLedgers = new HashSet<RequestLedger>();

public virtual ICollection<RequestLedger> OldRequestLedgers { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<RequestLedger> NewRequestLedgers { get; set; }

What am I missing here?

What's the PK of the RequestStatusType model? Is it a composite key (consisted from multiple columns)?

No, just a simple long:
```public long RequestStatusTypeId { get; set; }```


    ```builder.HasKey(x => x.RequestLedgerId);
    builder.Property(x => x.RequestLedgerId)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        .UseIdentityColumn();```


I figured out the problem. I had forgotten to add the new table to the OnModelCreating() method. The migration creation tool now runs as expected.
